# Test Input Transformer with Signal Generator

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, transformer, ltspice, ham-radio

I have an RF Amplifier kit that is not working.  The main problem is that the input transformer presents the radio with a high, unexpected SWR. It does amplify, so something works.

The transformer is wound as a T2:T.5 turns radio.  The below pictures display it.  I suspect that it might have a blob of solder shorting out part of it inside or a wire is cut.

I really do not know, the circuit is a simple class ab amplifier with mosfets and feedback.

I plan to unsolder various resisters and capacitors and feed an input signal into the transformer directly and see what come out the other side.

I have an oscilloscope and cheap ebay signal generator.  The signal generator I have can produce up to a 25 Mhz output into an open. Meaning, not into a 50 ohm load, like the usual signal generator.  If I attach a load, it should reduce the signal generator output.  Is the transformer a load, how much?

I am planning to operate this around 7.2 or 14 Mhz.

If I hook the signal generator to this transformer, will it be able to produce an output that I can measure?  Should I use am op amplifier / follower circuit to increase the power/buffer between the signal generator and the primary?

The input transformer is usually directly connected to the 50 ohm output of a transceiver.

I would expect to see outputs that are 25% of the input signal 180 degree phase reversed.

I would like to do experiments to see what the swr is and how the later mosfet , class ab amplifier  (with the feedback) affects it.  I suppose there is a way to do this by way of loadng the secondary?

Ideally, I can gather enough information to model this in LTSPice.  What this transformer is doing and its impedance is key.

Can I send my signal generator input into this transformer and get a useful measurement/learn something for ltspice?  Any other advice? Thanks

[image: schmadic]
[image: Amplifer]

[image: input transformer]

Comment: How are you going to measure, do you have an oscilloscope? Find out the output impedance of your sig-gen, and add resistors if needed to get it to 50 ohms. Then measure its output into a 50 ohm load. There's no need for high power to make a gain measurement, so even if your sig-gen won't drive 50 ohms at full output, that's not a problem. Then use it to measure the transformer. Do not use an opamp, one more thing to control and be suspicious of, you can't beat resistors for simplicity.

Comment: That doesn't look like a transformer to me; there only appears to be one winding AND, if that's all there is it'll be a really crappy input impedance for circa 10 MHz. Post a schematic.

Comment: @Andyaka The secondary a single turn through tubes terminating to the tiny PCBs at the ends of the binocular core. The ref des is T1. Or rather it's two half turns, with the mid point going through C3 to ground.

Comment: @Neil_UK I have an oscilloscope.  I can see what Pk-Pk goes in, by frequency.  My signal generator, as reviewed/tested by someone else states its output is described as going into an open load, not the usual 50 k ohms.  I  plan to connect one channel of the o scope to the input and one channel on the output and use it like that.

Comment: @Neil_UK OK I see it now! All the same, the input impedance will be shabby at circa 10 MHz.

Comment: @JeffreyEdwardMessikian Well don't be discouraged by what someone else says, adjust the sig-gen output impedance to 50 ohms, and then find out what level it **will** develop into a 50 ohm load. Even if 'adjust the output impedance to 50 ohm' means present the sig-gen with an L-pad that's 1k input impedance and 50 ohms output impedance.

Comment: @Andyaka  It is a transformer.  The secondary .5 turn is the solder you see in the picture.  Other people do have this transformer working.  It was a cheap $18 70 watt amplifier that supposedly works.  Other people have shown it working with videos.  Others have verified that the transformer is wound correctly.  I might have shorted something with solder or cut a wire.  The board can also be damaged.  It is a dirty amplifier with harmonics.  I just want to test the input transformer piece and see how that works and does do what the schematic says it should do.

Comment: @Neil_UK  A person who did a video review of my signal generator showed a video of a reported 5 volts pk to pk into an open.  When he added a 50 ohm load, it dropped to about half.  I figure I can adjust the generator to get a specific reading of pk - pk and watch the output of the transformer after I unsolder components on the board to isolate it from the mosfets.

Comment: @Neil_UK On your last Comment. I had to google L-Pad.  Lets say I set that up and my signal generator shows 5 volts Pk-Pk , on the L Pad Output, going into the transformer, 
 what do you mean when you say "will develop into a 50 ohm load"  The rest of the circuit with the antennae connected should be 50 ohms.  Do you mean to say test the sig generator output into the amplifier?  At first, I was just hoping to isolate the transformer and see if that / how that works.  If I have 5 volts from my sig-gen, than I should have 25 % less on the transformer in the same shape waveform.  I suppose.

Comment: @JeffreyEdwardMessikian if the output of the sig-gen halves when you connect 50 ohms, then it has a 50 ohm output impedance, you've just measured it. It sounds like it's capable of driving a 50 ohm load, you don't have to adapt it in any way. In a matched system, you get best results when everything is loaded properly. If you want to test the transformer by itself, then load each of its outputs to ground with 6 ohms

Comment: @Neil_UK  Some New Info,  I tell my sig-gen to output 4 volts pk-pk, 20 Mhz, sine wave.. My O-scope measures (at 20 Mhz) , 3.18 volts pk-pk into an open, sig-gen connected to o scope probes, I then connect a 50 Ohm load to sig-gen and measure 1.32 volts pk-pk on O-=scope,  I disconnect this setup and connect sig-gen to primary in my circuit, this is after i disconnect feed back resisters from mosfet and secondary leads to mosfet gates, i measure 2.65 pk-pk on the primary, on the secondary, i measure .672 pk-pk .. it appears the transformer is working properly, i checked both halves of secdry